# Association without ReferenceVersionField

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is it possible to have a OneToManyAssociationField as entity extension on for example ProductManufacturer without the ReferenceVersionField in my related custom entity?

If this is not possible, is it possible for the reference version field to have a custom name (so not product_manufacturer_version_id) On first sight, this also does not seem possible.

**About the error**

I am currently getting the following error when trying to search for manufacturers using `$criteria->addAssociation('myCustomEntity')`:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_manufacturer.myCustomEntity.product_manufacturer_version_id' in 'field list'
```

**About the big picture**

The use case is similar to the SeoUrl entity where there is a ‘foreign_key’ field which can have a relation to multiple entity types. My entity has not associations, but the other entities are extended to have an association to my entity. Just like the SeoUrl.

However, the DAL creates a query which uses the ‘product_manufacturer_version_id’ field, which does not exist on my custom entity…

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have a OneToManyAssociationField as entity extension on for example ProductManufacturer without the ReferenceVersionField in my related custom entity?

No, you must set a `ReferenceVersionField` when adding associations to the definition of a versionized entity. This is too deeply rooted in the basic principles of the data abstraction layer to work around.

> If this is not possible, is it possible for the reference version field to have a custom name (so not product_manufacturer_version_id) On first sight, this also does not seem possible.

You can change the storage name of the field. That is the name of the corresponding column within your database table. When you instantiate `ReferenceVersionField` you can use the second, optional argument to provide the storage name:

```php
public function __construct(string $definition, ?string $storageName = null)
```

The storage name should be provided in snake case. The name of the object property for the field will then be derived from the storage name and converted to camel case. So given you provide `my_version_custom_id` for the storage name, the object property of the entity will be `myVersionCustomId`.

Your entity may have multiple associations to different entities, but if those entities are versionized your foreign key constraint has to be a combination of columns for both the foreign primary key as well as the foreign version id.

Comment: Why does it work with the seoUrl? This entity has no reference version fields, yet does have a relation with products, categories, ... Also, is it possible to use the ReferenceVersionField without a (real) Definition? Because that will make it entity-dependant again :/

Comment: When you look at the `SeoUrlDefinition` you will find, that it actually doesn't have any associations to the entities that refer to it with `OneToManyAssociationField`. It only has a second generic `IdField` `foreignKey` (which contains the id of the `product`, `category` etc). This is a workaround. You could do it like that, but you'll have to explicitly set `foreignKey` and you can't use associations as you are used to, as you already found out. You can get a `seo_url` from a `product`, but you can't get a `product` from a `seo_url`, as it's missing reverse side associations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is exactly what I'm trying to do  My entity does not need an association to the other entity, but the other entity does need it. I want to do for example `$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('myCustomerExtension.field', 'foobar');` `$this->productManufacturerRepository->search($criteria, $context);`. But then I'm getting the SQL errors that it is missing fields :/ The other way around is not needed.